# is there any library which receives requests, sends response & also creates new requests

Tags: mocking, httprequest, wiremock, http-response-codes

Here is what I am looking for.
[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzUxw.png)

Step 1: My app sends post a request & the server (3rd party) receives it
Step 2: The third party server sends a response

I have achieved step1 & step 2 using wiremock (by stubbing the response)

Step 3: The thrid party should now send a new post request back to my app.

Comment: Can you edit the title please? Remove "based" or add words to say "based on what".

Comment: Done.. .. last few words were truncated

Comment: Hi @SankethKamath. Yes, there is such tool. Check this out: https://apisimulator.io/docs/latest/standalone-api-simulator/callback.html